# Story about a man sent to prison for murdering one of the first aliens on Earth who is then being hunted by another of the species

Tags: story-identification, books, aliens

I read a science fiction book in the middle school library around 2005.

The point of view started as first person and after a few chapters it switched to third person (but was about the same man). I think it was told as a letter, or perhaps a journal, that was written while the man was in prison.

He was sent to prison for murdering one of the first aliens to arrive on Earth, but there was a lot of controversy as to whether the law applies to alien species. Eventually, another alien (possible wife or sister) of the same race came down to inflict her own punishment on the murderer, but he always managed to escape her pursuit.

In the end, the alien manages to subdue the prisoner to the point of holding a knife to his neck, and at that point they kiss and end up teleporting to the alien world to live together. Unfortunately the man eventually dies because the atmosphere of the alien planet doesn't bode well for his physiology.

Does anyone have a clue as to what the name of this was?

Answer (score -1):

Could this be "Illegal Alien" by Robert J Sawyer? From memory it's a courtroom drama about an alien (first contact with Earth) who is being prosecuted for murder.

Comment: Other than there being an alien and a murder, none of the other plot points match.